# access a certain line from a file and change it using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I have a XML File and I need to access that file in Javascript.
I need to get a certain line and change it.

Here is an example:

```
changeFileCode("data.xml", 12, "New Data"); 
// The first paramater is for the file we want.
// The second paramater is the line we want.
// The third paramater is the new content we want written
```

#### Is there a way to do it?

P.S.: I don't want a piece of code that has 1000 lines.

Comment: Try rephrasing your question, not forgetting to add what you've tried for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @nyedidikeke i dont know what to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** rely on Line/Columns numbers in XML. because XML neglect white-spaces.

But you can target a specific node and change its value using JQuery.

Let's say you want to do that from a client-side, *because that's what javascript do*, you will have to get that XML file from the server, in purpose to edit the particular parts then send it back to the server to save it; for example:

```
   $.get("yourGetUrl.php", function(data) {
      var xml = $(data);

      xml.find("yourNode").text("yourNewData");

      $.post("yourPostUrl.php", xml, function(resp) {
        alert(resp);
      }, "xml");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot directly access the local file system. The safe way to do this would be to get the user to provide the file via an 
    `<input type="file"/>`
element.

You can then manipulate the file using the [File Api](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/%20File%20Api)

The user will then need to re-save the altered file.

The other way to achieve this would be to write a server side api using whatever technology you fancy (php/asp etc) to manipulate files based on parameters and then call it using ajax from your web page.